# What should I do with a rude customer

Tags: professionalism

I work in an ERP development company, which our customers are others companies. Recently our support team has complained about a specific customer who is very impolite and says bad words to our support team without reason (we know that he is new using our software and still need training, but he thinks that he knows everything about the application).

What should we do to prevent and stop this? We already have spoken with his boss and nothing changed, his boss often is traveling. We don't record the phone calls, but we have 3 or 4 e-mail from him proving his unprofessional actions.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere I'm the responsible for documentation/test department. We are a small company, so I would like to help my team.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should we do to prevent and stop this? We already have spoken with his boss and nothing changed, his boss often is traveling. We don't record the phone calls, but we have 3 or 4 e-mail from him proving his unprofessional actions.

You can't stop a rude person from being rude - and working in support, you're going to encounter people who are downright rude and unprofessional. (In some ways you're lucky if it's just the one guy!)

The only way of "solving" the situation for good is just to let go of the rude customer, then you don't have to deal with him anymore. But that's not practical in the vast majority of cases, so you usually have to find some way of making life easier on the support team dealing with them, rather than dealing with his attitude directly.

Just a few ideas:

- Talk to the team and make sure they know that *you know the guy's an arse*. Sometimes the biggest frustration is when you're supporting the nastiest person around, yet management say "ah, he's not that bad in person", or even "well, it must be your style of response that's getting his back up". Empathise with the team.
- Find someone who you know isn't affected by this guy's rudeness, and ask if you can assign all his cases to him. Don't force this upon anyone at all, but some people just don't care about the tone of whoever is writing in. Heck, some people I've known get a kick out of it!
- Make it clear that if anything crosses the line, then they should just drop the case and forward it onto you to deal with. You can then decide how you want to respond from there, without the rest of the team worrying about saying the wrong thing.

Of course, it goes without saying the the *wrong* way of dealing with this is to be rude back - that won't reflect well on anyone!

Answer (score 1):

Keep calm polite and professional

Try to understand that he is frustrated and taking out on you and the rest of the team.

Perhaps a little hand holding may help

Comment: We are always polite, but he keeps doing that. Seems that he is trying to convince his boss that our software is wrong all the time, even the support team helping him with his own mistakes.